# Return value of mmap when using ptrace

Tags: c++, linux, return, mmap, ptrace

I was learning how to use ptrace and I faced a strange problem:

I wrote a program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    long x=(long)mmap(0,-235,2,34,-1,0);
    printf("Child: x=%ld (",x);
    for(int i=31;i>=0;i--) printf((x&(1<<i))?"1":"0");
    printf(")\n");
    printf("Child errno: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

It simply makes an mmap syscall with wrong parameter. Then it prints return value (also in binary) and errno.

Here I have this program's output after executing it:

```
Child: x=-1 (11111111111111111111111111111111)
Child errno: Cannot allocate memory
```

And I run it with strace:

```
execve("./nic.e", ["./nic.e"], [/* 35 vars */]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="dom", ...})   = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9237000
brk(0x9237cd0)                          = 0x9237cd0
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0x9237830, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
brk(0x9258cd0)                          = 0x9258cd0
brk(0x9259000)                          = 0x9259000
mmap2(NULL, 4294967061, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7798000
write(1, "Child: x=-1 (1111111111111111111"..., 47Child: x=-1 (11111111111111111111111111111111)
) = 47
write(1, "Child errno: Cannot allocate mem"..., 36Child errno: Cannot allocate memory
) = 36
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

And strace tells that this wrong mmap returns -1 with error ENOMEM.

Till now everything is OK.

Here my code with ptrace (I cut everything not really needed):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    int pid=fork();
    if(!pid)
    {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,NULL,NULL);
        execve("nic.e",NULL,NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    while(true)
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid,&status,0);

        if(WIFEXITED(status)) return 0;

        int signal;

        if(WIFSTOPPED(status))
        {
            signal=WSTOPSIG(status);
        }

        if(WIFSIGNALED(status)) return 0;

        if(signal==SIGTRAP)
        {
            user_regs_struct regs;
            ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS,pid,NULL,&regs);

            if(regs.orig_eax==__NR_mmap2)
            {
                static bool mmap_back=false;
                if(!mmap_back) mmap_back=true;
                else
                {
                    mmap_back=false;
                    long x=regs.eax;
                    printf("mmap return: %ld (",x);
                    for(int j=31;j>=0;j--) printf((x&(1<<j))?"1":"0");
                    printf(")\n");
                }
            }
        }
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,pid,NULL,NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It should print same things that the child prints - retrun values of mmap2 syscalls.

But here's the output:

```
mmap return: -12 (11111111111111111111111111110100)
mmap return: -1216753664 (10110111011110011101000000000000)
Child: x=-1 (11111111111111111111111111111111)
Child errno: Cannot allocate memory
```

Why did mmap return -12? Am I capturing the return value incorrectly?

Comment: `ENOMEM` is 12 on my system, which matches the -12 return value. Strace is probably just translating it into the normal -1 return value with errno set to ENOMEM (12) you'd see as a user. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a decent reference at the moment.

Comment: Missed the edit window: Check parts 3.3 and 3.4 [here](http://www.int80h.org/bsdasm/#return-values)

Comment: Thank You for explanation. I thought that c functions simply make system calls and don't change anything. This link was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 32-bit x86 linux %eax contains either the return value or the negated error value on error.

See e.g. [4.4](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html) or [3.3 and 3.4](http://www.int80h.org/bsdasm/#return-values).

A return value of -12 from the syscall means that the function failed and errno should be set to 12, which at least on my system matches `ENOMEM`.

It appears that strace is helpfully translating this for you. If you want your application to behave as strace, you should perform a test and translation similar to the one in [4.4](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html):

```
if ((unsigned long)(x) >= (unsigned long)(-2048)) {
    printf("syscall failed. errno = %ld\n", -(res));
}
```

Comment: It's actually 133 at the moment, but I think 2048 should be safe to use.

Comment: Note also there is possibly confusion between the return values/conventions of the *system call* `mmap` and the C library `mmap()`, which takes the results of the system call and interprets them in some way to return something meaningful to the user. `ptrace` is showing the results from the system call, not the C library call.